# I think I broke the "investigate the mayor" mission by sequence breaking?

Tags: else-heart-break

So I made myself a "brute force" key and got in to Longson's apartment way early, and found out about and triggered the conversation with his "wife."

Now I've been giving a mission to find dirt on Longson, but going back and trying to talk to the wife again doesn't seem to do anything.

Is there a specific action that completes the mission, or am I gonna have to restart the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, talking to the "wife" early breaks the mission and you have to restart.